# Using sample on Iris in R

Tags: r

I'm super new to R and struggling with the following excercise:

"Choose a random species from Iris and pull without putting back 50 rows that are not that species".

Iris:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
..
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
```

I've come up with this so far:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- sample(150, 1)
y
x <- iris[y,5]
x
```

Which results in:

```
> set.seed(1)
> y <- sample(150, 1)
> y
[1] 68
> x <- iris[y,5]
> x
[1] versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Now I know that I have to sample all of Iris and choose 50 that are not versicolor. How could I do that?

I've tried something like this:

```
z <- sample(iris, 50, replace = FALSE, iris.species != x)
z
```

If anyone could enlighten me on how to use the sample command I'd be thankful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a random `Species`, `unique(iris$Species)` gives unique values of `Species` and `sample` to get 1 random value.

```
select_species <- sample(unique(iris$Species), 1)
```

Use `subset` to drop that species from the dataset.

```
result <- subset(iris, Species != select_species)
```

To chose random 50 rows from `result` you may do

```
sample_50 <- result[sample(nrow(result), 50), ]
```

Or as @r2evans suggested -

```
sample_50 <- dplyr::slice_sample(result, n = 50)
```

Comment: Doesn't `result` need to be sampled?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Why does `result` need to be sampled ? I am reading  only `"Choose a random species from Iris and pull without putting back 50 rows that are not that species".`

Comment: Thanks but r2evans is correct. I would have to sample 50 random results from the subset without the random species that was chosen. How does that work?

Comment: Perhaps similar to `dplyr::sample_n(result, 50)`?

Comment: @DidseaJ You may check the updated answer to get random 50 rows.